# How to extend database schema for new requirements of mandatory and optional participation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, schema

I have an application for managing events in our institution. Recently a new program for the staff was started and i was asked to handle it in the same application. This new program for staff has two paths, Group 01 is for recently hired people and Group 02: is for experienced people.

So For every year there will be like 12-15 events. e.g.

```
EV-001 - Skill 01 --- Mandatory
EV-002 - Skill 02 --- Mandatory
...
EV-013 - Skill 13 --- Optional
EV-014 - Skill 14 --- Optional
```

Program for Newly Hired staff will require them to participate in 5 specific events in a year, lets call mandatory events. These events can change over the years. That for Next year they can include different 5 events.

Program for Experienced staff will require them to participate in ANY 5 events in a year (from 1 to 14).

I already have Following tables

1. Employee Table
2. Events Table (event table has an "event tag" field which i initially planned to use)
3. Participation Table (for keeping records of participation in any event)

So the first issue is how to expand my database such that I can handle new requirements. As I mentioned that I was planning to use the "Event Tag" field in my Event Table to declare 2 types of events, Mandatory and Optional. and for group 01, I check if they have participated in 5 mandatory types of events and for Group 02, I check if they have participated in 5 events from Mandatory + Optional. 
So the issue is that if a participant participate in "EV-002 - Skill 02" twice then his participation should only be counted once, not twice.

In the end, i need to display how many people participated in this program and how many finished it from each group and each batch.

So is there any flexible and simple solution to this problem?

I am using MS SQL with ASP.NET/C#

Comment: You aren't getting any responses here because this is not very clear. It is so broad that the only way to answer this would be to design the database for you. And that can't happen because we don't know any of the actual requirements. As it sits right now this is not answerable.

Comment: I already said that i have a full database for event management, But i need to extend it such that we can identify the employees who have participated in a particular set of workshops. and employees are divided in two groups. One who has to attend specific events and others who need to attend specific number of events from a list of events.
My question is: how can i handle the logic of participation required by an employee in the database and not on the code side. I don't know how to simplify it.

Comment: Well we don't know what your current architecture is so how could anybody know what you need to do to extend it. I understand you want to extend your database but there just isn't details about what you have and what you are trying to do. Start by posting the ddl for the tables that you have and an explanation of what you want to accomplish. Remember that we don't know your application or the requirements so you have to explain things in more detail than you would the person working next to you.

Answer (score 0):

After trying and discussing it some of the colleagues I have adopted a solution that might be helpful for others.

I created 5 new tables. First one is

```
Program Event Table 
(Columns)
 - Event  ID 
 - Event Name
 - Description 
 - More Fields
```

Second Is

```
Program Participants Group Table 
(Columns)
 - Group ID 
 - Group Name
 - Description 
 - Mandatory Events Required
 - Optional Events Required
 - More Fields
```

Third is

```
Program Events Group Table 
(Columns)
 - Event ID (FK)
 - Group ID (FK)
 - Mandatory (bit field) 
 - Optional (bit field)
 - More items if required
```

The Fourth table is

```
Program Participants Table (listing the registered participants) 
(Columns)
 - Participant ID 
 - Employee ID (FK)
 - Group ID  (FK)
 - Batch ID  (FK)
 - More items if required
```

and the final table is

```
Program Batch Table (For distinguishing between different batches) 
(Columns)
 - Batch ID 
 - Batch Start Date
 - Batch End Date
 - More items if required
```

I filled the Program Events Group table with the the list of events related to the program and their requirement criteria for each group. 
So If Event 01 -- Skill 01 is required for Group 01 and is optional for Group 02 then the Program Events Group table will have 2 entries.

```
Event 01, Group 01, 1, 0, ...
Event 01, Group 02, 0, 1, ...
```

But if Event 08 -- Skill 08 is option for Group 02 but is not required by Group 01 then it will have only 1 entry in the table.

```
Event 08, Group 02, 0, 1, ...
```

Now I added the **Event ID**  from the Program Event Table to the existing Event table, so if a new event belongs to this program then Program event ID will be added. So now the existing participation table is used and the existing event table is also used.